# KVO related exception for managedobject keypath observer that includes a relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, key-value-observing, kvc

I have a key path being observed in the init method of a viewController. ( event is a property of this viewController

```
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
   ...// some code
   [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"event.location.title" 
             options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
   ...// some more code
}
```

event is a managed object, and it has a 1-1 relationship with location. (each event has 1 location object and vice versa)

strangely, if the "location" relationship isn't fired before the event object is set to the property viewController.event, then I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Cannot update for observer <NSKeyValueObservance 0x17627340> for the key path 
"location.title" from <Event 0x176de540>, most likely because the value for the key 
"location" has changed without an appropriate KVO notification being sent. Check the 
KVO-compliance of the Event class.'
```

This error is fixed, as I said, if I add the following line before setting the managed object into the property of the viewController in which case it doesn't crash, and works correctly

```
Location* location = event.location;
viewController.event = event;
```

Obviously this is a workaround. Any ideas on correcting this?

## **EDIT**

I have thought that maybe using `setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` for the `NSFetchRequest` that I used for the `NSFetchedResultsController` with the @"location" keypath would be a prettier workaround for the bug, but  strangely this bug has disappeared for the moment. The only thing I did was further the development of the app, which means that I did reinstall the app several times. So maybe it will resurface when the DB gets larger again. I'll update this if it happens

Comment: What are you doing with the `location` before any of that is run?

Comment: In this case nothing special. Just presenting its name and address value in a table cell. It's not modified in any way. The exception, I'm pretty sure, occurs when the fault is fired, when the tableCell accesses the location relationship. Because this occurs with the observer at event.location.name was already set (since I set it in the init, for the whole keypath so I don't need to set it every time the event property is changed)